# Clear the page after an itemize or enumerate, but only if it's the outermost one

Tags: lists, environments, page-breaking

I'm working on a technical document in which each page has an image followed by a list of information/actions in an itemize or enumerate environment. I'd like to make sure that the page is cleared after each such list, without inserting manual `\clearpage` commands. What's the best way to redefine the itemize/enumerate environments so that they run `\clearpage`? One difficulty is that there can be nested lists, and I only want to clear the page after the outermost list ends.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1.png}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item Sub-list 1
        \item Sub-list 2
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2.png}
...
```

Actually, the pics are included using figure commands with the `[t]` flag. The issue I'm having is if the list is very short, then the next list starts on the same page, rather than following on from the image on the next page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `enumitem` package and and create a new list type, writing something like this in the preamble (supposing you'll have at most 3 levels):

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{info}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[info,1]{after=\clearpage}
```

This way, each *first* level `info` list ends up in a `\clearpage`. In the arguments of `\setlist`, of course, you can add other specifications as to formatting labels, list layout, &c.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm sure it would do exactly what I asked for. Unfortunately, I wasn't quite as clear with my question: I wanted to do this without using a different environment. I'm actually writing the document in markdown, using pandoc to convert it to LaTeX before compiling, and it seems easier to work with the LaTeX template than to change how pandoc outputs lists.

Comment: Then use `enumerate` and write `\setlist[enumerate,1]{after=\clearpage}`. I defined a new list type so that ordinary enumerate environments are not changed. Or even simply write for each such list: `\begin{enumerate}[after=\clearpage]`.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, using `\setlist` is the best option I've found. As a bonus it gives me more control over spacing around the lists, which I was also looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer to this myself, and somebody else might find this useful. Since I didn't want to change the environment used (as in @Bernard's answer) a change to how enumerate worked was needed. In the latex source I found how the environment is defined, and this was my solution:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myendenum{%
    \ifnum \@enumdepth > 1%
        \endlist%
    \else%
        \endlist\clearpage%
    \fi}
\let\endenumerate\myendenum
\makeatother
```

The check on `\@enumdepth` makes sure that sub-lists don't break. My first guess was to compare with 0, but 1 worked as I wanted.